# Translator not working on helper class

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, helper, translate

I try to translate a text in a function inside `sales_helper_data` with this code `$this->__('TEXT')` but it just returns the same input string.

I Also tried `Mage::helper('sales')->__("TEXT")`, `Mage::helper('Admin')->__("TEXT")`. Admin due to my module is admin module and created `Mage_sales.csv` in `local/[lanfuage]`

I Debugged the code and the `Mage::app()->getTranslator()->getData()` is an empty array. what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. 
I should add the translator file to module `config.xml` file

```
</adminhtml>
  <translate>
    <modules>
      <company_Sales>
        <files>
          <default>company_Sales.csv</default>
        </files>
      </company_Sales>
    </modules>
  </translate>
</adminhtml>
```